# How to get text from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys i am new to javascript and having a problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Temp </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
   document.forms["EventConfirmRedirection"].submit();
    }</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var formData = {        

                    name: alex
                    email: alex@example.com
                                }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="EventConfirmRedirection" method="post" action="http://requestb.in/14ewbma1">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="test1-suc"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="test2-suc"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want name and email in the formdata object and post it.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to fill the `value` attribute (I added id's to make things simpler but you can also do it with e.g.: `document.getElementsByName("name")[0]`)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Temp </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  fillandsubmit();
};

var formData = {name: "alex", email: "alex@example.com"}

function fillandsubmit(){
  var i1 = document.getElementById("name");
  var i2 = document.getElementById("email");
  i1.value = formData.name;
  i2.value = formData.email;
  document.forms["EventConfirmRedirection"].submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="EventConfirmRedirection" method="post" action="http://requestb.in/14ewbma1">
    <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="test1-suc"></input>
    <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="test2-suc"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```